# Generating a range based on a number in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I’m trying to make a field show the range of number between 1 and the number in another field and with a preceding identifier.
For instance, when the field labeled “TotalQuestions” has a value of “5”, I would like another field, say “TableInfo”,  to be populated by “Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA function

```
Public Function GenerateRepeatedText(maxNumber As Long) As String
Const PrefixText = "Question"
Const SeparatorText = ", "
Dim i As Long, rtn As String
rtn = ""
For i = 1 To maxNumber
    rtn = rtn & PrefixText & i & SeparatorText
Next
If Len(rtn) > 0 Then
    '' trim trailing separator
    rtn = Left(rtn, Len(rtn) - Len(SeparatorText))
End If
GenerateRepeatedText = rtn
End Function
```

can be used in a query like this:

```
SELECT TotalQuestions, GenerateRepeatedText([TotalQuestions]) AS TableInfo FROM ...
```

Comment: I suggest accepting answers if they are correct.  Otherwise, people may be less inclined to help you in the future.  Just my thought :)